# Is there a more efficient way to re-write multi if-else statement

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to ask is there a more efficient and proper way to re-write my following code (simply because there are a lot of if-else statements)

the key_list in the following is a list of lists that each contains some DNA bases, e.g. key_list = [['-'],['A'],['A','T'],['C','G','T']] and '-' is used to present a special gap.

I got an idea is to use a dictionary to build a mapping relationship between these statements, but not so sure about the correctness.

```
output = []
for l in key_list:
    if len(l) == 1:
        output.append(l[0])
    elif len(l) == 2:
        if set(l) == set(['A', 'G']):
            output.append('R')
        elif set(l) == set(['C', 'T']):
            output.append('Y')
        elif set(l) == set(['A', 'C']):
            output.append('M')
        elif set(l) == set(['G', 'T']):
            output.append('K')
        elif set(l) == set(['G', 'C']):
            output.append('S')
        elif set(l) == set(['A', 'T']):
            output.append('W')
        else:
            print('Error!')
    elif len(l) == 3:
        if set(l) == set(['A', 'T', 'C']):
            output.append('H')
        elif set(l) == set(['G', 'T', 'C']):
            output.append('B')
        elif set(l) == set(['A', 'G', 'C']):
            output.append('V')
        elif set(l) == set(['A', 'T', 'G']):
            output.append('D')
        else:
            print('Error!')
    elif len(l) == 4:
        output.append('N')
    else:
        output.append('-')  # if there is only '-' in the column, also add it.
```

Comment: my answer has even better complexity that just storing the set in a variable.

Answer (score 2):

you could use `tuple(sorted(set(l)))` to create a key for a dictionary:

```
elif len(l) == 2 or len(l) == 3:
    key = tuple(sorted(set(l)))
    output.append(lookup_dict[key])
```

where `lookup_dict` is something like:

```
lookup_dict = {('A', 'G') : 'R',
      ('C', 'T') : 'Y',
      ('A', 'C'): 'M',
      ('A', 'C', 'T') : 'H',   # note that it's A,C,T, not A,T,C, sort order!

 }
```

... and so on (merging both cases of length 2 and 3)

notes:

- tuples are sorted alphabetically or `tuple(sorted(set(l)))` wouldn't match. `tuple` conversion is needed so keys are *hashable* (`list` won't do)
- the lookup complexity has dropped from `O(n)` with your method (plus the useless & multiple `set` creation) to `O(1)` thanks to the dictionary.
- the code does not handle the "error" case. If there isn't a match, you'll get a `KeyError`, probably better than `print('Error!')`. If you want to test first use `key in lookup_dict` condition.

As suggested in comments, `frozenset` can also be used as a dictionary key. In that case, the code is simpler:

```
elif len(l) == 2 or len(l) == 3:
    key = frozenset(l)
    output.append(lookup_dict[key])
```

and `lookup_dict` needs some more pre-processing to convert keys as `frozenset` type (but doesn't require key elements to be sorted, which is less error-prone):

```
lookup_dict = {frozenset(k):v for k,v in lookup_dict.items()}
```

But after this, the solution is probably slightly faster.

Comment: Many thanks for your quick reply, I will definitely try it.

Comment: You don't need to use `tuple` or `sorted` if you just convert directly to `frozenset` instead of `set`. `frozenset` can be used as a `dict` key, so you save yourself the cost of a couple shallow copies and a sort step by using it directly.

Comment: that's true. No need to sort with this. But the dictionary is a little harder to write. Unless you write it with tuples, then convert afterwards